How to use DocumentPictureInPicture API with Flutter Web?
I created a function enterToPip for Flutter to call. The enterToPip function works as follows:
async function enterToPIP() {
    try {
        if (!documentPictureInPicture.window) {
            // Open a Picture-in-Picture window
            const pipWindow = await documentPictureInPicture.requestWindow({
                width: 1100,
                height: 700,
            });

            const flutterWebElement = document.querySelector("body");
            pipWindow.document.body.appendChild(flutterWebElement);
            pipWindow.addEventListener('pagehide', () => {
                document.body = flutterWebElement;
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('(enterToPIP) Error with Picture-in-Picture:', error);
    }
}

The problem is that when Picture-in-Picture is opened, the web inside the Picture-in-Picture window is not clickable but still shows the content according to the web's behavior.
Here is the error when clicking on the web inside the Picture-in-Picture window:
Error
dart:sdk_internal 12007:11                                             throw_
dart:sdk_internal 12363:30                                             nullCheck
dart:sdk_internal 178101:118                                           activateSystemCursor
dart:sdk_internal 179067:68                                            [_sendPlatformMessage]
dart:sdk_internal 178877:33                                            sendPlatformMessage
packages/flutter/src/services/text_editing_delta.dart.lib.js 10016:38  send
packages/flutter/src/services/text_editing_delta.dart.lib.js 4969:313  _invokeMethod
dart:sdk_internal 48066:34                                             runBody
dart:sdk_internal 48102:7                                              _async
packages/flutter/src/services/text_editing_delta.dart.lib.js 4967:20   [_invokeMethod]
packages/flutter/src/services/text_editing_delta.dart.lib.js 5062:34   [_invokeMethod]
packages/flutter/src/services/text_editing_delta.dart.lib.js 5058:36   invokeMethod
dart:sdk_internal 48066:34                                             runBody
dart:sdk_internal 48102:7                                              _async
packages/flutter/src/services/text_editing_delta.dart.lib.js 5057:20   invokeMethod
packages/flutter/src/services/mouse_cursor.dart.lib.js 445:57          activate
packages/flutter/src/services/mouse_cursor.dart.lib.js 290:19          handleDeviceCursorUpdate
packages/flutter/src/rendering/wrap.dart.lib.js 83465:35               [_handleDeviceUpdate]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/wrap.dart.lib.js 83508:40               <fn>
packages/flutter/src/rendering/wrap.dart.lib.js 83424:7                [_deviceUpdatePhase]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/wrap.dart.lib.js 83491:37               <fn>
packages/flutter/src/rendering/wrap.dart.lib.js 83413:7                [_monitorMouseConnection]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/wrap.dart.lib.js 83490:40               updateWithEvent
packages/flutter/src/rendering/wrap.dart.lib.js 83850:49               dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js 405:14               [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js 376:43               handlePointerEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js 365:14               [_flushPointerEventQueue]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js 340:40               [_handlePointerDataPacket]
dart:sdk_internal 207767:7                                             invoke1
dart:sdk_internal 178849:15                                            invokeOnPointerDataPacket
dart:sdk_internal 180683:49                                            [_sendToFramework]
dart:sdk_internal 180592:31                                            onPointerData
dart:sdk_internal 181229:24                                            <fn>
dart:sdk_internal 181207:9                                             <fn>
dart:sdk_internal 180850:11                                            loggedHandler
dart:sdk_internal 69535:14                                             _callDartFunctionFast1
dart:sdk_internal 69473:22                                             ret

I tried creating a web page using an iframe to load Flutter Web, but I encountered a problem: when I put the iframe inside the pipWindow, Flutter Web reloads, causing the state of the app to be lost.
My goal is to have Flutter Web enter Picture-in-Picture, where it can display the content in the same state as the main web page. When closing Picture-in-Picture, it should return to the main page and continue functioning as expected.
